# Express or other Web servers html include private static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webserver

When running web server, and we want to access a static file
,we'll set a router that can access these file

for example in Express using `express.static()`, we set a path to access static files from `localhost:3000/public/fileName.type` somthing like that.

So when sending HTML or template to client,
we can include css/js/img...files by this path like `<script src="public/index.js"></script>` ,

this will get files from `localhost:3000/public/index.js`

But these files are **public**, I mean everyone can access these files from `localhost:3000/public/fileName.type`

So How can we include files in **private** way?

something like `<script src="absulutePath/index.js"></script>`

But this not working because `absulutePath/index.js` will refer to Client computer's path, Not my server's.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: In order to serve a file it needs to be publicly available, irrespective of whether you use an absolute (i.e `src="http://example.com/pictures/pic.png`) or relative (i.e `src="pictures/pic.png"`) path.

Comment: so you mean there's no way to include private files in html?

Comment: Private in what way? Either a file can be served from a directory to the client (public) or it can't (private). Are you trying to mask the URL from which the asset is served?

Comment: I want my sources in html to be private( maybe access from server local file),rather than putting files on URL to access

Comment: The sources will always point to a location on a server, be it on the same domain or an external server. It's still unclear what you're trying to achieve, but whatever it is, it sounds like it's not possible.